# PHP IIS images displaying as broken (localhost)

Tags: php, html, iis

I'm having a hard time trying to get images displayed on my localhost IIS.

I have a simple PHP server running that displays an image within a gallery directory within the same folder. Here is the directory layout:

```
 -> server.php
 |
 -> gallery
    |
    -> 1.jpg
    -> 2.jpg
    -> 1.txt
    -> 2.txt
```

I have my HTML page post a request to handle an image. The simple PHP file contents:

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $image = $_POST["image"];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <h1>Welcome <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
    <br>
    <h2>you have chosen <?php echo $image; ?></h2><br>
    <img src="./gallery/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg"/>

</body>
</html>
```

And all of the echo's work fine. If I look at the inspector and hover over the broken image to see the URL that is being used to follow the image it points directly to where my image is hosted: `http://localhost/gallery/1.jpg`

Is there some extra setting I have set up on IIS in order for this to work properly?

To also ensure that I'm not going crazy, I added txt files to check if I can read the contents from them with the similar style:

```
<?php
  $txtFile = './gallery/1.txt';
?>

<p><?php echo file_get_contents( $txtFile); ?> </p>
```

and in fact, it did print the content of the text file without a problem. Seems to only have an issue handling pictures.

Comment: open your browser and right-click on the broken image and select inspect element and check the value of the image tag.also make sure you enable the static content feature of iis. and check mime type in iis  mime-type is available: .jpg mime type:image/jpeg and .jpeg : image/jpeg . [img](https://i.imgur.com/39dGTny.png). and in code <img src="./gallery/<?php echo $image; ?>.jpg"/> you put the .jpg etention directly so check the image exention in the folder.

Comment: which browser you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your MIME Type Settings in your IIS, if your image extension is match with any MIME Type. If it is not there you can add the new one with the configuration

- extension ".jpg"
- MIME Type : "image/jpeg"